# C++ character concatenation with std::string behavior. Please explain this

Tags: c++, string

Here are some cases about c++ std::string which I couldn't understand.

1.

```
string ans = ""+'a';
cout << ans << endl; //Prints _string::copy
```

2.

```
string ans="";
ans=ans+'a';
cout << ans << endl; //Prints a
```

3.

```
string ans="";
ans = ans + (5 + '0'); // Throws error
```

4.

```
string ans="";
ans += (5 + '0'); //works
```

5.

In a code, I had the line 
 `ans += to_string(q);`  q was a single digit integer. The program threw runtime error.

Changed it to `ans+= (q+'0');` and the error got removed.

Please help with clearing the idea.

Comment: `""+'a'` will go to out-of-range and invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: `ans += to_string(q);` should work correctly if `q` is an integer.

Comment: How is it out of range? is adding a character to a string valid when + is not overloaded?

Comment: `""` is not a `std::string`, it's an array of `char` and when you add an integral type to it you perform pointer arithmetic on the address of that array. That's very very different to concatenation.

Comment: Neither you nor anyone else can overload operators where both sides are basic types. So, `""` is (decays to) a char const *` and `'a'` is a `char`, which means you're adding the ASCII number of character `a` to the address of that particular empty string... thus going out-of-bounds and invoking UB. But if you want the `std::string` literal you mistakenly expected, then do `using namespace std::string_literals; auto wow = "a std::string"s`.

Comment: Ok. I get the 1st and the 2nd case now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string ans = ""+'a';
```

"" is an address of an empty string literal. 'a' gets interpreted as an integer, ASCII code 65. This adds 65 to an address of a literal string, which results in undefined behavior, possibly a crash.

```
ans=ans+'a';
```

`ans` is a `std::string`. `std::string` defines an overloaded `+` operator. Several, actually. One of them, in particular, overloads `+` where the parameter is a character, and it appends the character to the string.

```
ans = ans + (5 + '0'); // Throws error
```

`5+'0'` is an expression that's promoted to an `int` type. `std::string` does not unambiguously overload the `+` operator with an `int` as the parameter. This result in a compilation error.

```
ans += (5 + '0'); //works
```

`std::string` does have an unambigous overloaded `+=` operator, so this compiles fine.

Comment: In 5th case also `5+'0'` is promoted to `int`. So, how is it any different from 4th case?

Comment: Different operators. `+` versus `+=`, define different overloads.

Comment: Ok so + is not defined for int and += is defined for int. Got it. Thanks.

Comment: No, `+=` is not defined for `int`. It is defined only for `char`, but there are no other overloads for `operator +=` that an `int` parameter can be converted to, hence no ambiguity.

Comment: Can you quote an example where there is an ambiguity in `+` operation but not in `+=`?

Comment: C++11 adds an `operator+` for an rvalue reference to a `std::string`, which uses move semantics. An `operator+` with an `int` can be converted to either a regular copy-based `operator+`, that takes a char parameter, or a move-based `operator+` that takes a char parameter, hence the ambiguity. There are, obviously, no move semantics for an `operator+=`.

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
std::string ans = ""+'a';
```

is not what you think, you actually perform the same operation as below:

```
const char* p = "";
p = p + 97 /*97=='a'*/; // increase p pointer by `a` value, results in UB (pointer to random memory)
std::string ans = p; // p points to possibly unallocated memory (UB).
```

which makes little sense.

if you compile it with clang you will get long list of warnigns:

```
main.cpp:22:25: warning: adding 'char' to a string does not append to the string [-Wstring-plus-int]
    std::string ans = ""+'a';
                      ~~^~~~
main.cpp:22:25: note: use array indexing to silence this warning
    std::string ans = ""+'a';
                        ^
                      & [   ]
main.cpp:22:25: warning: adding 'char' to a string pointer does not append to the string [-Wstring-plus-char]
    std::string ans = ""+'a';
                      ~~^~~~
main.cpp:22:25: note: use array indexing to silence this warning
    std::string ans = ""+'a';
                        ^
                      & [   ]
```

Answer (score 3):

String literal is an array of characters. It it not an instance of `std::string`. Arrays cannot be passed to functions or operators by value, but instead they decay to a pointer to first character, when used an operand.

Characters are numbers that encode symbols. All characters have a non-zero value, except for `'\0'`.

In the expression `""+'a'`, the string literal decays to pointer, then `'a'` character is iterpreted as a non-zero integer. This value is added to the pointer. Regardless of the value of `a` (It happens to be 65 in the commonly used ASCII encoding), the result is beyond the bounds of the array. Pointer arithmetic out of bounds has undefined behaviour, and the output 1. is the result of the undefined behaviour.

---

The program 2. has well defined and expected behaviour.

---

> ```
> ans = ans + (5 + '0'); // Throws error
> ```

There is no `operator+` that accepts arguments `std::string` and `int`. The right hand argument is `int` because the `char` argument in `5 + '0'` is promoted to `int` so that both arguments are of same type. This is also the return type of the expression.

This is where it gets hairy. There is an `operator+` that accepts `char` and `int` is convertible to `char`. However, there are also other possible conversions that are ambiguous. Here is the error shown by clang:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') and 'int')

    ans = ans + (5 + '0'); // Throws error

          ~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~

./include/c++/6.1.0/bits/basic_string.h:4982:5: note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter '_CharT' ('char' vs. 'int')

    operator+(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs, _CharT __rhs)

    ^

./include/c++/6.1.0/bits/basic_string.h:5036:5: note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter '_CharT' ('char' vs. 'int')

    operator+(basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&& __lhs,
^
```

... And many other potential overloads.

---

> ```
> ans += (5 + '0'); //works
> ```

This works because  `operator+=(char);` is an unambiguous overload.

---

> In a code, I had the line ans += to_string(q); q was a single digit integer. The program threw runtime error.

[Works fine here, no errors thrown.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86b15d4ee853d0b6)

Comment: *Arrays cannot be passed to functions or operators* Well they can be passed by reference,

Comment: @NathanOliver qualification added.