# C++ Stack Overflow what is causing it?

Tags: c++, string, vector

I am new to C++ and wrote the following:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<string> fizzBuzz(int n) {
        vector<string> result(n);
        for (int i=1;i<=n;++i)
        {
            if (i%3==0 and i%5==0)
                result[i-1]="FizzBuzz";
            else if (i%3==0)
                result[i-1]="Fizz";
            else if (i%5==0)
                result[i-1]="Buzz";
            else result[i-1]=""+i;
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

when the input is 1 I am getting overflow error, why is that? the last line seems the problem but I think it's totally fine.

Comment: think about what it means to ""+i; where i is an int.  After you think about it, give https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668760/converting-an-int-to-stdstring a look?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ character concatenation with std::string behavior. Please explain this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38573571/c-character-concatenation-with-stdstring-behavior-please-explain-this)

Comment: This is not an "Stack" overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `""+i` doesn't convert the integer value in `i` to a string. Instead it's the same as `&(("")[i])`. I.e. it's a pointer to the i:th value of the string `""`. Which is out of bounds since the empty string only have a single element at index `0` (the string terminator).

Use [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) instead:

```
result[i-1]=std::to_string(i);
```

Comment: Thanks, from your experience which method is faster? to use % or since the input is continues to use counters (until 3 and 5)?